# Delete space in a specific column using sed or cut

Tags: awk, sed, space

I have file `a.pdb` as

```
ATOM      1  N   ARG     1     -19.794 -23.351   -9.550  1.00  0.00           N
ATOM      2  H1  ARG     1     -20.314 -23.948   -8.920  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM      3  H2  ARG     1     -18.811 -23.572   -9.490  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM      4  H3  ARG     1     -20.049 -23.660  -10.480  1.00  0.00           H
ATOM      5  CA  ARG     1     -20.087 -21.926   -9.380  1.00  0.00           C
```

I want to delete one space between field 7 and 8, without changing the format, but just shifting one character  backwards. The Decimal points should appear in column 35, 43 and 51 (now they are on 35, 43 and 52).

Comment: @Jotne, How to keep the format for asking questions? For example, my a.pdb didnt keep the intended format, but your edit regained it. How to do it?

Comment: Use the code formatting tool `{}`, which indents everything 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^(.{46}) /\1/' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing with cut:

```
cut -c 1-46,48- < a.pdb
```